# C program to generate n number of prime numbers

Tags: c

I've written the following code to generate prime numbers from 1 to n.

What changes should be made to this code in order to generate n number of primes?

For example, if the input is `n=10`, then the list of prime will be:

```
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getValueFromUser();
void PrintListOfPrime(int value);

int main() {
    int value = getValueFromUser();
    PrintListOfPrime(value);
    return 0;
}

/* Reads a number from user */
int getValueFromUser() {
    int value;
    printf("Please enter the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    return value;
}

void PrintListOfPrime(int value) {
     int  ValueIsPrime; //ValueIsPrime is used as flag variable

     printf("The list of primes: ");

     for (int i = 2; i <= value; i++) {
         ValueIsPrime = 1;

         /* Check if the current number i is prime or not */
         for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
             /*
              * If the number is divisible by any number
              * other than 1 and self then it is not prime
              */

             if (i % j == 0) {
                ValueIsPrime = 0;
                break;
             }
         }

         /* If the number is prime then print */
         if (ValueIsPrime == 1)
            printf("%d, ", i);
     }
     printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: If you have written this code, you should also be able to do the required modifications. It's really easy.

Comment: Instead of looping to get primes up to the value of `n`, you would have to count how many primes have been found and loop to the desired number of primes. Easy. You should be able to do it.

Comment: count how many prime numbers you have to discover and change first `for` by a `while` or a `do...while` and check inside your new condition